# Como hacer un ciclo forEach doble con condición javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo 2 objetos uno con un listado de actividades que cargo desde la base de datos, otro objeto que me carga las actividades que tiene seleccionado mi proyecto, mi idea es hacer un ciclo forEanch en donde pueda validar si el actividad_id lo elimine me lista de actividades para que no puede se seleccionado de nuevo.

a la fecha tengo esta función.

```
  selectActividadADD(itemObj){
    this.actividad.forEach((actividad, index) => {
        itemObj.forEach((item, indexItem) => {
          if(actividad.actividad_id == item.actividad_id){
            this.actividad.splice(index,1);
          }          
      });
    });
  }
```

haciendolo así me funciona si solo tengo una actividad en mi proyecto, pero si tengo varias actividades tendría que ejecutarla función varias veces.

cual seria la mejor opción

Comment: ¿Por qué no guardas el id en un set? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: gracias por el dato